# GroupBy + Case When Sum(x) > 0 then Sum(x) else 0

Tags: linq, group-by, sum, case-when

How can I replicate following in LINQ

```
SELECT KEY_COLUMN,
        CASE WHEN SUM(COLUMN2) < 0 THEN SUM(COLUMN2) ELSE 0 END AS NewColumn
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY KEY_COLUMN
```

till now I could come up with following

```
var result = from a in source
               group a by a.Key_Column
                   into g
                   select new
                   {
                       Key_Column = g.Key,
                       NewColumn = g.Where(item => item.Column2 < 0)
                                    .Sum(item => item.Column2)
};
```

above code is not really summing up the Column2 before deciding if it's a negative number or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from a in db.Table
            group a by a.Key_Column into g
            let sum = g.Sum(item => item.Column2)
            select new {
               Key_Column = g.Key,
               NewColumn = sum < 0 ? sum : 0
            };
```

Comment: I believe your version is more efficient, but when I have too many columns to do this kinds of conditional things to come up with a value, do you recommend using the way I have done it in my reply below? (sorry couldn't format it in this comment so i posted it as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

isn't this the same ?

```
var query = from r in db.Table
  group r by r.KEY_COLUMN into g
  select new {
    KEY_COLUMN = g.Key,
    NewColumn = g.Sum(x => x.COLUMN2) < 0 ? g.Sum(x => x.COLUMN2) : 0
};
```

Comment: Almost, in this case Sum will be calculated twice